# PHP - Add specific background color in table row

Tags: php, mysql, css, highlight, cells

I have a table which has the following structure:

```
+--------+---------+----------+
|Col1    | Col2      | Col3   |
+-----------------------------+
| BRA1   | QI        | QI     |
+--------+-----------+--------+
| BRA2   | Validated | QI     |
+-----------------------------+
```

I would like to higlight cell in red when it is equal to `'QI'` and in green color when it is equal to `'Validated'`.

This is what I did, but it doesn't work. Can any anyone could help to fix my script?

### My php script:

```
<?php

$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
echo '<h1>Table:'.$tablename.'</h1>';
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
echo '<td>'.$field[$i]->name.'</td>';
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
    if($cell=="QI"){
        //echo "<td>$cell</td>";
        echo '<td BGCOLOR="#ff0000">'.$cell.'</td>';}
        elseif ($cell=="Validated") {echo '<td BGCOLOR="#3f9a0e">'.$cell.'</td>';} //Green color BGCOLOR="#3f9a0e"

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysqli_free_result($result);


?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanna use `foreach` inside `while` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
...
$fields_num = mysqli_num_fields($result);
echo '<h1>Table:'.$tablename.'</h1>';
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
echo '<td>'.$field[$i]->name.'</td>';
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
foreach($row as $cell) {
    if($cell=="QI"){

            echo '<td style="background:#ff0000">'.$cell.'</td>';

    } elseif ($cell=="Validated") {

            echo '<td style="background:#3f9a0e">'.$cell.'</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your script, but it colors cells but there is an issue. In output, contents are missing while I am displaying results. Plus first column, instead of displaying BRA1, BRA1, I have QI, Validated. So I was wondering if there isn't any issue with if and elseif statement.

Comment: Down vote? My answer is in line with your question. You could improve your question.

Comment: It works now, I forgot to put another condition when it is not Validated or QI. After the elseif, I added, `else {echo "<td>$cell</td>";}`

Answer (score 1):

You need the style attribute and change the background-color

```
<td style="background-color: #ffffff">...</td>
```